# Java code for closing a desktop application after pressing the x button

Tags: java, awt

i need a little help with introducing a method or something, that will close the desktop application after i press the default X button in the corner. I struggled with a lot of methods i found online, but i either don't know where to put it or i'm missing something...

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Calculator implements ActionListener {

Frame frame = new Frame();
Label label1 = new Label("First Number");
Label label2 = new Label("Operator");
Label label3 = new Label("Second Number");
Label label4 = new Label("Result");

TextField text1 = new TextField();
Choice choice = new Choice();
TextField text2 = new TextField();
TextField text3 = new TextField();
Button button = new Button("Calculate");

Calculator() {
    label1.setBounds(50, 100, 100, 20);
    label2.setBounds(50, 140, 100, 20);
    label3.setBounds(50, 180, 100, 20);
    label4.setBounds(50, 220, 100, 20);
    text1.setBounds(200, 100, 100, 20);
    choice.setBounds(200, 140, 100, 20);
    text2.setBounds(200, 180, 100, 20);
    text3.setBounds(200, 220, 100, 20);
    button.setBounds(200, 200, 100, 20);

    frame.add(label1);
    frame.add(label2);
    frame.add(label3);
    frame.add(label4);
    frame.add(text1);
    frame.add(choice);
    frame.add(text2);
    frame.add(text3);
    frame.add(button);

    button.addActionListener(this);

    choice.add("+");
    choice.add("-");
    choice.add("*");
    choice.add("/");

    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400, 350);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        double number1 = Double.parseDouble(text1.getText());
        double number2 = Double.parseDouble(text2.getText());

        String selectedOperation = choice.getSelectedItem();

        if (selectedOperation.equals("+"))
            text3.setText(String.valueOf(number1 + number2));
        else if (selectedOperation.equals("-"))
            text3.setText(String.valueOf(number1 - number2));
        else if (selectedOperation.equals("*"))
            text3.setText(String.valueOf(number1 * number2));
        else if (selectedOperation.equals("/")) {
            if (number2 != 0)
                text3.setText(String.valueOf(number1 / number2));
            else System.out.println("Can't do that...");
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
        System.out.println("You can only introduce numbers!");
    }
}
}

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Calculator();
}
}
```

Some help would be very appreciated, as i'm trying to learn Java!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure why you are using AWT rather than Swing. As the latter tends to be recommended over the former.

But nevertheless - you can make the application exit by adding a window listener. E.g.:

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
                                {
                                    @Override public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
                                    {
                                        System.exit(0);
                                    }
                                });
```

As a side note, if you were using Swing rather than AWT (i.e. a `JFrame` rather than `Frame`) you can also do :

```
JFrame jframe = ....;
jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: I'm taking a java development course, and it's segmented on various chapters, and this is some kind of assignment for the AWT part. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

No one uses the AWT GUI anymore. Use Swing, JFrame, JButton, JLabel, JTextField. And then [`JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)).